# Async attribute in script element not working?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

When I load a script from an external server in the following manner

```
<div id="verisign-logo">
    <script type="text/javascript" src=verisign-url>
</div>
```

The script gets executed and a flash file is displayed in the div with Id verisign-logo.
Verisign-url is a predefined variable.

Now I am trying to load and execute the script asynchronously.I  added async attribute to the script tag in the following manner

```
<div id="verisign-logo">
    <script type="text/javascript" src=verisign-url async=true>
</div>
```

But the weird thing is script gets appened in the div however the flash file doesnot get displayed.What exactly is not right here?

Comment: that is what `asych` is supposed to do.

Comment: @pilot hey there I dont get you

Comment: I think your flash stuff requires script which you are loading asynchronously ..SO you cannot guarantee it will be available at the time you expect flash to work..

Comment: You're missing `</script>`. Is that a copying error or in your real code?

Comment: @Pilot The flash image is returned by the script that I am loading.

Comment: @Barmar hey that's just a copying error.My real code is proper.

Answer (score 1):

With reference from w3schools syntax for async loading is as follows

```
<script src="demo_async.js" async></script>
```

[W3School Async script loading](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp)

Comment: As far as I know that's what HTML5 compatible browsers accept what about browsers that donot support HTML 5?

Comment: Then you required to specify that condition while asking question

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.I was in a hurry my bad.But you seem to be an extremely smart guy why didnot you make sure before answering?